# @font-face issues in Firefox/Mac & iPad

Tags: css, ipad, firefox, font-face

I have a few weird issues I need to solve.

First, let me show my @font-face declarations in my CSS file.

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Conv_Gotham-Book";
src: url("fonts/Gotham-Book.eot");
src: local("☺"), 
    url("fonts/Gotham-Book.woff") format("woff"), 
    url("fonts/Gotham-Book.ttf") format("truetype"), 
    url("fonts/Gotham-Book.svg#Gotham-Book") format("svg");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: "Conv_Gotham-Light";
src: url("fonts/Gotham-Light.eot");
src: local("☺"),
    url("fonts/Gotham-Light.woff") format("woff"), 
    url("fonts/Gotham-Light.ttf") format("truetype"), 
    url("fonts/Gotham-Light.svg#Gotham-Light") format("svg");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: "Conv_Gotham-Medium";
src: url("fonts/Gotham-Medium.eot");
src: local("☺"), 
    url("fonts/Gotham-Medium.woff") format("woff"), 
    url("fonts/Gotham-Medium.ttf") format("truetype"), 
    url("fonts/Gotham-Medium.svg#Gotham-Medium") format("svg");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: "Conv_Gotham-Bold";
src: url("fonts/Gotham-Bold.eot") format("eot");
src: local("☺"),
    url("fonts/Gotham-Bold.woff") format("woff"), 
    url("fonts/Gotham-Bold.ttf") format("truetype"), 
    url("fonts/Gotham-Bold.svg#GothamBold") format("svg");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Problems:  Hyperlinks using any of those custom fonts don't work in only one browser/platform combination  Firefox 13.0.1/Mac (Example here: http://lonely-dev.com/leapfrogbeta/?page_id=896 on the headlines, )

Second Problem: Font disappears on iPad2/Safari browser.

Everything else is fine, would love some insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared to use a font called "Journal" in your css for `.custom .headline_area h2 a` in `custom.css` while in the above code example you're calling for the Gotham Family (which, btw, has no web license at the moment). Journal is loaded correctly in both Firefox/Mac and iPad/Safari. Links work in both.

Update: the font loads fine in all mentioned cases but the links aren't working. This is because of `a` being an inline element. Also, declaring a height for the heading `a` is a bad idea. Just use this rule:

```
.custom .headline_area h2 a {
  display: block;
}
```

and the links will work.

Another thing is that you should declare the heading font on the h1, h2 etc. and not just on their contained links.

Comment: yeah, I was testing another custom font to see if that was the problem.  I put it back, check again?

Comment: still works in all test scenarios mentioned by me. Correction: font displays fine, links aren't working. But seriously, do you have a web license to use Gotham on your website as embedded web font? Currently, H&F doesn't have one for [Gotham](http://www.typography.com/fonts/font_styles.php?productLineID=100008). With the existing non-web license over there you would have to pay $1299.25 for 50 visitors...